# Python Iterating over lists in lists with map()

Tags: python, lambda, filter

So my intention is to iterate over lists in lists with map, filter and lambda
e.g.:

> [ [33,3,3,0] , [34,1,0,4] ]  should result in [ [33,3,3] , [34,1,4] ]

```
   def no_zeros(lst):
      a=map(filter(lambda x:(y==0 for y in x) ,lst),lst)
      print (list(a))
      #(says that filter is not callable)
```

I know that this code won't work but i do not know what exactly i do wrong since i'm still kind of new to lambda,etc.I already tried different stuff , like moving the filter after the lambda,but that did not seem to work either . Im gratefull for any kind of tipps or help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`map` applies the function in first parameter to the second parameter. It tries to call your `filter` object...

A fixed version would be:

```
list(map(lambda z: list(filter(None,z)),lst))
```

(still not very clear even if it yields the expected result... it took me 3 or 4 tries to get it right by trial & error, and the fact that `filter` & `map` need to be iterated upon in Python 3 doesn't help and kills the whole hype about those fashionable keywords)

At this point of `lambda/map/filter` complexity you'd be better off with a list comprehension:

```
lst = [ [33,3,3,0] , [34,1,0,4] ]

result = [ [x for x in sl if x] for sl in lst]

print(result)
```

result:

```
[[33, 3, 3], [34, 1, 4]]
```

Comment: Thanks , i did think that other methods,like list comprehension might be the better idea here , but i wanted to learn/try out more with lambda/map/filter. Thats why i chose to try it this way. Again thank all your help though.

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that `map` expects a function/callable as a first argument but you're giving it the result of a `filter`.

You can fix this by applying `filter` to the sublists iterated by `map`:

```
def no_zeros(lst):
    a = map(lambda x: filter(lambda y: y != 0, x), lst)
    print(list(a))
```

---

By the way, you can do the same thing with list comprehensions:

```
def no_zeros(lst):
    a = [[y for y in x if y != 0] for x in lst]
    print(a)
```

Comment: Thanks , this actually helped me alot with the understanding of everything .

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = list(map(lambda k: list(filter(lambda l: l != 0, k)), lst))
```

This should do the trick. You need apply a lambda on each element in the list through a filter. Be aware nested lambdas are ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possibility:

```
import itertools
a = [ [33,3,3,0] , [34,1,0,4] ] 
list(map(list, map(filter, itertools.repeat(bool), a)))
# [[33, 3, 3], [34, 1, 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution might be:

```
def no_zeros(lst):
   if isinstance(lst, list):
      for i in lst:
          while 0 in i:
              i.remove(0)
      print(lst)
   else:
      raise TypeError("lst must be type of list")
```

Comment: careful! `remove` only removes the first occurrence of the element.

Comment: yeah you right, i did some changes to avoid this problem!